# Zend_Translate scan translation files

Tags: zend-framework, localization, gettext

I've trying to use Zend_Translate from Zend Framework

I am using "POEdit" to generate "gettext" translation files.

My files are under /www/mysite.com/webapps/includes/locale  (this path is in my include path).
I have:
pictures.en.mo
pictures.en.po
(I plan on having pictures.es.mo soon)

It all works fine if I manually do addTranslation() for each file. However I want to use the automatic file scanning method.

I tried both of those:

```
<?php
/*Localization*/
require_once 'Zend/Translate.php';
require_once 'Zend/Locale.php';
define('LOCALE','/www/mysite.com/webapps/includes/locale');

if(!empty($_GET['locale'])){
    $locale = new Zend_Locale($_GET['locale']);
}
else{
    $locale = new Zend_Locale();
}

$translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext', LOCALE, null,  array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME));


if ( $translate->isAvailable( $locale->getLanguage() ) ){
    $translate->setLocale($locale);                                          
}
else{
    $translate->setLocale('en');
}
```

And this:

```
<?php
/*Localization*/
require_once 'Zend/Translate.php';
require_once 'Zend/Locale.php';
define('LOCALE','/www/mysite.com/webapps/includes/locale');

if(!empty($_GET['locale'])){
    $locale = new Zend_Locale($_GET['locale']);
}
else{
    $locale = new Zend_Locale();
}

$translate = new Zend_Translate('gettext', LOCALE);


if ( $translate->isAvailable( $locale->getLanguage() ) ){
    $translate->setLocale($locale);                                          
}
else{
    $translate->setLocale('en');
}
```

In both cases, I get a Notice: No translation for the language 'en' available. in /www/mysite.com/webapps/includes/Zend/Translate/Adapter.php on line 411

It also worked if I tried to do directory scanning.

Answer (score 1):

i think there is just one little "bug".

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
       'gettext', 
        LOCALE, 
        null,  
        array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY) // <--    
);
```

If you use LOCALE_FILENAME, is ZF searching inside this FILE for your Translation.

Comment: I picked "FILENAME" so that it would scan the file name "pictures.en.mo" and find "en". That's what I understand from the documentation. "DIRECTORY" would require me to maintain a directory structure per language.